# SQL Server database with vs without filestream

Tags: java, sql-server

I want to ask a question about SQL Server and filestream.

Actually I was not aware about it.

I have a small Java application where I store some `.pdf` files to a database. I just converted those files programatically to binary and saved them as `varbinary(max)` data type.

But as requirement increased, the volume of pdf files also increasing. And now my database is running out of space.

So I googled it and read about filestream. I have gone though some tutorials, but before actually trying it on a live database, I want to clarify my question: will that feature help me or not?

Saving document directly as binary, and saving through filestream share freeup some space in my database? Really? Because in both cases we store them in `varbinary(max)` columns - so how can it help me?

Comment: The point is: with `FILESTREAM`, the **contents** of the files isn't actually stored inside SQL Server - it's stored in the file system, and only "mapped" to SQL Server - as if it were stored there. If you ask for the datalength of a FILESTREAM column - SQL Server will actually go out to the file system and query the size of the file - the **actual bytes** of the file are **NOT** stored inside SQL Server's data pages.

Comment: one more question. plz.. can i enable file stream on existing database..as my database already have varbinary column with lots of files in it.. will it store them as file stream.

Comment: or will i need to insert all those files again?

Comment: If you want to put those file into a filestream store, you need to have the physical files on disk - having them in the table as `varbinary(max)` doesn't help, really. Once you've created the filestream share, you need to copy the files to that location

Comment: i AM SORRY but i am not getting your point.

Comment: i have a row in a sql table. where i want to save a pdf file to a specific row index. i dont want to just put them in table. there are other columns too. so just putting files in folder how will map them to specific row item????

Comment: let say i have pdf1  , i want to save it to primary column value "abc1'

Comment: just like employee details tables. where we can store. emp id wise data. and want to attach the respective pdf file to correct emp id